# Why do I need to build a project after changing an assembly it references?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

**Scenario**: I have multiple solutions, each with a number of projects which references an assembly produced by another solution.

```
Solution A
  - Project A (Reference B,C,D,E)
  - Project B (Reference D,E)
  - Project C (Reference D,E)
Solution B
  - Project D (Reference F,G,E)
  - Project E (Reference F,G)
Solution C
  - Project F
  - Project G
```

**Question:** Would it be possible to create a single directory which includes all of the .DLL files produced by the projects solution B and C, and then for Solution A to reference this single folder?

Currently Project A, B, C all have a copy of all of the .DLL files produced by the assemblies they reference. (Projecty A,B and C are all C# Web Projects) Projects D,E,F,G are C# class libraries.

I'm using IIS 7 (for if this has any impact on the answer).

Comment: You can specify the output directory under your project's properties -> Build -> Output -> Output path; and set a common directory for all projects in `B` and `C`. Then you can reference the assemblies from there. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @DominicKexel yeah that's what I was considering doing but using MSBuild like so "MSBuild SolutionB.sln /p:OutputPath=c:\SomeBinDir" etc. I've noticed when building SolutionA that it creates a copy of the .dll files into its own /bin directory. It's this copying of .dlls that i wan't to prevent, as it's really time consuming for a large number of projects.

Comment: You can prevent that by setting `Copy Local` to `False` in the Reference Properties.